# WriteFile Sockets Handle issues

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to port some C which uses read() and write() functions for sending sockets. I am trying to port this to windows and it is suggested (from what I have read) to use WriteFile and ReadFile to accomplish my task.

I read according to Microsoft API documentation that WriteFile will accept a socket. But I am unsure why its not working

(Beginner C Coder)

```
SOCKET sock;
```

I set sock to a socket type

```
WriteFile((HANDLE *)sock, data, 17, NULL, NULL);
```

Now I know I am doing some thing wrong with that (HANDLE *) type cast but I get an error saying that **"int cast to pointer with out a type cast"** if I don't (or something similar).

So my question is how can I send a socket using WriteFile as well as read a socket using ReadFile

*cheers

ty

Comment: Can you show us how you obtained `sock` ? Also, do you know you can use [`send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740149) instead of `WriteFile` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WriteFile` wants a handle, not a pointer to a handle. You probably want to use:

```
WriteFile((HANDLE)sock, data, 17, NULL, NULL);
```